# Change Color in react material UI ListItemIcon

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying listitem icon red but not getting how to make it red.

I am very new to reactJS and Material UI icon

this is my button:

```
    <ListItem button>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <ShoppingCartIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Orders" />
    </ListItem>
```

Can anyone help me how to make the icon color red?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 360
  },
  icon: {
    color: 'red',
  }
});
export default function List(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <List component="nav">
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>
            <InboxIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is an [article](https://material-ui.com/api/icon/) about it (`className` use-related).

Answer (score 1):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
 listItem: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
      color: theme.palette.primary.main,
      '& .MuiListItemIcon-root': {
        color: theme.palette.primary.main,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can override the style of the component with a rule name of the classes object prop.

Here is the answer with an example:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12023