# Can't change icon colors using material UI styling

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material UI styling to style a list and while it changes the color of the text the icons won't change color unless inline styling is used. Inline styling is not a viable solution to as I plan to have switchable theme.

Below is the code

```
             <ListItem
                button
                variant="contained"
                selected={selectedIndex === index}
                key={text}
                component={Link}
                to={url}
                disabled={disabled}
                className={classes.listItem}
                classes={{
                  selected: classes.selected,
                }}
                onClick={(e) => handleListItemClick(e, index)}
              >
                <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
                <Typography variant="button">
                  <ListItemText
                    primary={text}
                    primaryTypographyProps={{
                      variant: "h1",
                      style: { fontWeight: "600" },
                    }}
                    className={classes.txt}
                  />
                </Typography>
              </ListItem>
```

And the styling

```
listItem: {
padding: "1.5vh",
color: theme.palette.background.paper,
"&:hover": {
  backgroundColor:  theme.palette.primary.main,
},
"&:hover$icon": {
  color: theme.palette.primary.main,
},
"&:hover$txt": {
  color: theme.palette.primary.main,
},
"&$selected": {
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
  color: theme.palette.primary.main,
  fill: theme.palette.primary.main,
  // border: "1px solid #2699fb",
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
  },
},
"&$selectedSection": {
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
  color: theme.palette.primary.main,
  fill: theme.palette.primary.main,
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
  },
},
```

}

Comment: https://material-ui.com/api/list-item-icon/#listitemicon-api, you can apply classes to listItemIcon tag, eg: classes={{
                  root: classes.Icon,
                }}

Comment: ListItemIcon is a separate component of its own so you could override its style or define it manually. It will not inherit the style of the ListItem component if that is what you are expecting. This should answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58683082/change-color-in-react-material-ui-listitemicon

Comment: @iismaell although this solves the problem of assigning the icon a color, the color won't change according to the selected state.